Definition of "balanced graph"
I have been searching the definition of balanced graph and, knowing the consensus of defining it using average degrees, it appears that some places use several other definitions for the term "balanced". My question is: are these definitions related to each other? Currently, I could not figure out the conection between them.
For the rest of the post, $G=(V,E)$ is a graph without loops or multiple edges, where $V$ and $E$ are the set of vertices and edges respectively. The definitions are the following.

Definition 1 (the most common): Suppose that $G$ is finite and for all $H=(V_H,E_H)\subseteq G$, denote $d_H:=\frac{|E_H|}{|V_H|}$. It is said that $G$ is balanced if $d_H\leq d_G$ for all subgraph $H$.


Definition 2 (reference): $G$ is balanced if every induced cycle has length $0\pmod{4}$.


Definition 3 (reference): Let $G$ be finite of order $n$ and denote by $A$ the adjacency matrix. $G$ is balanced if the equation $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{1}_n$ has a rational solution, where $\mathbf{1}_n:=(1,\ldots,1)$.


Definition 4 (reference): Let $G$ be a directed graph. $G$ is balanced if $d_v^\text{in}=d_v^\text{out}$ for all $v\in G$.

I know this is a huge question to answer. An insight on some equivalences or some counterexamples would be really helpful. Also, I could not provide any attempt on proving / disproving the relations, but I am really stuck in even proposing a first idea. I know Definition 4 is for directed graph, but the induced simple graph might be related to the others.
Also, some references of these terms might be really helpful. Tank you very much!

Interesting question. For definitions 1 and 2, consider the graph $C_3$ (cycle a length 3). According to definition 1, it is balanced (subgraphs are $H=C_2$ with $d_H=1/2$ and $H$ with one vertex and $d_H=0$,  and $d_G=1$). According to definition 2, it is clearly not balanced. Is that (a bit of) what you are searching for?

@Kolakoski54 Yes, this is what I am looking for. Thank you for your comment. This would prove that Def 1 does not imply Def 2. I thought this was a basic topic in graph theory (that is why I asked here in MSE), but probably the term "balanced" has been overused.

There is also a definition for balanced signed graphs, which doesn't correspond to any of your definitions...

The term "balanced" in Graph Theory might be the equivalent of the term "normal" in mathematics: means whatever you want.

For bipartite graphs specifically, there is an even more common notion of "balanced" unrelated to any of the others - a balanced bipartite graph is one with a bipartition where the two parts have equal size.

None of these imply the others, and they exist for different purposes. I will try to explain what they're for, and then give some examples showing that the definitions are all inequivalent. (We wouldn't expect them to be, because they're made for different reasons, this is just for our peace of mind - and because it's a fun game.)

The point of Definition 1 is to describe graphs whose edges are about equally distributed. This comes up in the study of random graphs, where we ask: how many edges does a large random graph $G$ need to have, before we can be reasonably confident it contains a specific small subgraph $H$? This question has a relatively nice answer if $H$ is balanced. If $H$ is unbalanced, and has a subgraph $H'$ with $\frac{e(H')}{v(H')} > \frac{e(H)}{v(H)}$, then in some sense $H'$ is the "bottleneck" for copies of $H$ appearing in the large random graph $G$: it takes a while for $H'$ to appear, but once it does, we suddenly end up with many copies of $H$ "around" it.
By the way, the quantity $\frac{e(G)}{v(G)}$ is sometimes called the density of $G$, and it is exactly half of the average degree of $G$ (so definition 1 could also be stated in terms of average degree).
Definition 2 seems to be a bipartite generalization of perfect graphs, though I don't know too much about it. Perfect graphs have no induced odd cycles; all bipartite graphs are perfect, because they have no odd cycles period. In a bipartite graph, you can similarly try to exclude induced cycles of length $4k+2$ for all $k$, to get something "even more perfect than perfect".
I don't know where Definition 3 comes from; I can observe that it's a bit like a generalization of regular graphs. Regular graphs are balanced, and we can take $\mathbf x = \frac1d \mathbf 1_n$, where $d$ is the degree of every vertex.
It is clear why graphs satisfying Definition 4 are called "balanced": the number of edges into a vertex "balances" the number of edges out of a vertex! These graphs have an Eulerian tour through every connected component. The related class of undirected graphs is the class of even graphs (where every vertex has even degree). Every even graph can be oriented to make it balanced by Definition 4: take an Eulerian tour through each component, and orient edges the way that the tour traverses them.

For examples where the definitions disagree, let's first look at trees.

All trees are balanced by the first definition: if a tree $T$ has $n$ vertices, then $\frac{e(T)}{v(T)} = \frac{n-1}{n}$, every subtree $T'$ of $T$ has $\frac{e(T')}{v(T')} = \frac{k-1}{k}$ for some $k < n$ (which is less), and every subgraph which is not a tree has even smaller density than a tree subgraph of the same size.
All trees are balanced by the second definition, trivially: they have no cycles at all.
Some trees are balanced by the third definition, and some are not. For example, a path on five vertices $1,2,3,4,5$ is not balanced: the equation at vertices $1$ and $5$ forces $x_2 = x_4 = 1$, but the equation at vertex $3$ asks for $x_2 + x_4 = 1$. Every star $K_{1,n}$, on the other hand, is balanced (giving the middle vertex value $1$ and all leaves value $1/n$).
No orientation of a tree (with at least two vertices) is balanced by the fourth definition: every such tree has a leaf, which will either have out-degree $1$ and in-degree $0$, or vice versa.

Definitions 1 and 2 disagree on the complete graphs $K_n$ for $n\ge 3$. These are balanced by definition 1 because they have a record-setting density: $\frac{e(K_n)}{v(K_n)} = n-1$. (No subgraph on $n$ vertices can beat this, because we lose edges without losing vertices. A subgraph on $k<n$ vertices can have density at most $k-1$: the density of $K_k$.) However, by definition 2, these are not balanced, because they contain $3$-cycles. They are once again balanced by definition 3 (since they're regular); they have a balanced orientation by definition 4 only when $n$ is odd.
If we take two copies of $C_4$ and join them at a vertex, this is balanced by definitions 1, 2, and 4, but not 3 (for a similar reason to the 5-vertex path). It stays balanced by definition 2 if we add a new vertex adjacent to only one existing vertex, but stops being balanced by definition 1 (since the original graph had a higher density) and by definition 4 (since the new vertex has degree 1).
A $k$-regular graph is always balanced by definition 1 (since all subgraphs have maximum degree $k$, so their average degree can only be less) and by definition 3 (as mentioned earlier). For all $k$, there are examples that are not bipartite, and therefore not balanced by definition 2. They have an orientation that's balanced by definition 4 when $k$ is even, but not when $k$ is odd.
If we take any $2$-regular, $3$-regular, and $6$-regular graph, and join them together by a new vertex with a neighbor in all three graphs, this is balanced by definition 3: give the vertices in the three original graphs values $\frac12$, $\frac13$, and $\frac16$ respectively, and the extra vertex value $0$. It is not balanced by definition 1 (the $6$-regular graph is a denser subgraph) or by definition 4 (due to the degree-$3$ vertices), and can definitely fail to be balanced by definition 3 (if the $2$-regular graph is a cycle of the wrong length). If we do the same thing with a $2$-regular graph and three $6$-regular graphs, we get a graph balanced by definitions 3 and 4, but not 1.

Thank you very much for your well-explained answer! I thought finding the solution was a tedious task and you achieved disproving the equivalences of all definitions with really simple examples. It was really insightful.
